# My If statement is giving me a "Run time error 13: Type mismatch" message

Tags: excel, vba

Let me give you a bit of background before my question. I'm trying to parse a large text file (250,000+ pages), and pulling values from it. I'm using specific variables to get the values I'm looking for as you see below. However, my `If` statement (the long one at the top of my sample code) gives me the message

> "Runtime error 13 type mismatch"

See code below:

```
If rptText Like "(0825)" And _
   Trim(Mid(rptText, 85, 9)) = "(0826)" And _
   Trim(Mid(rptText, 85, 9)) = "(0827)" And _
   Trim(Mid(rptText, 85, 9)) = "(0828)" And _
   Trim(Mid(rptText, 85, 9)) Then

    cusip0095 = True

  Do
    rptText = ts.ReadLine

    If rptText Like "*MF OMNI*" Then

        mfOmni0095 = Trim(Mid(rptText, 78, 13))
        Exit Do
    End If

    If rptText Like "*CONTROLLED*" Then

        total0095 = Trim(Mid(rptText, 78, 13))
        Exit Do
    End If
  Loop
```

---

Any help from you all would be great, and thanks in advance!

Edit: after trying the answers, I need to explain a bit more. The variables I referenced (0825, 0826, 0827, 0828) are for parsing values that are 9 characters long. Here's a couple of examples of how it looks like on a file:

(0825) 461308108

or

(0826) 921908109

I want any values that have the variable 0825, 0826, etc. ahead of it to pick up those values, which is why I was saying my trim is Trim(Mid(rptText, 85, 9)). Any suggestions?

Comment: Thats some interesting code you have there

Comment: You are getting error because of this line in IF `Trim(Mid(rptText, 85, 9)) Then` What are you comparing the Trim statement with? Also your IF condition doesn't make sense. How can `Trim(Mid(rptText, 85, 9)) = "(0826)"` and `Trim(Mid(rptText, 85, 9)) = "(0827)"` be true at the same time? Did you want to use `OR`?

Answer (score 3):

You have your problem If statement on several lines, which is not allowed in VBA. You need to use the underscore "_" character (Continuation character in this case) to let the compiler know this is a single line of code:

```
If rptText Like "(0825)" And _
   Trim(Mid(rptText, 85, 9)) = "(0826)" And _
   Trim(Mid(rptText, 85, 9)) = "(0827)" And _
   Trim(Mid(rptText, 85, 9)) = "(0828)" And _
   Trim(Mid(rptText, 85, 9)) Then
```

As Siddharth Rout mentioned, your logic has problems. There is no way Trim(Mid(rptText, 85, 9)) can equal "(0826)" AND "(0827)".

Try something like this:

```
Dim ThisTextPart As String
ThisTextPart = Trim(Mid(rptText, 85, 6))

If rptText Like "*(0825)*" Or _
   ThisTextPart = "(0826)" Or _
   ThisTextPart = "(0827)" Or _
   ThisTextPart = "(0828)" Then
```

Comment: + 1 :) BTW in the original post the IF was in one line. The wrapping was done by `Trinimon` See the revision history. Also that `Someone Else` in your above post is me :)

Comment: Thanks, guys! I'll try either scenario and see if I can get it to run. Again, thanks for all the input. :)